# PHP code to show featured image caption if it exists

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation, caption

I want to display featured image caption in a paragraph only if it exists.

I am trying the following without luck:

```
<?php if (the_post_thumbnail_caption()) { echo '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . the_post_thumbnail_caption() . echo '</p>' } ?>
```

and it's resulting in fatal error:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\builder\wp-content\themes\BuilderChild-Default\extensions\magazine-enhanced2\functions.php:88:syntax
>   error, unexpected T_ECHO

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

You have redundant `. echo` near `'</p>'`. This should be:

```php
<?php 
  if (the_post_thumbnail_caption()) { 
     echo '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . the_post_thumbnail_caption() . '</p>'; 
  }
?>
```